# How can I read multiple query parameters having the same name in Mule?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Given the URL `https://localhost:8081/api/Location?Name=Germany&Name=America`, is there a way to read the query parameter in such a way that the output is a comma separated value set?

Expected Output:

```
["Germany", "America"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [Multi-Value selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-selectors#multi_value_selector):

```
#[attributes.queryParams.*Name]
```

Note that the output is a list of values. List are not "comma separated" in memory. If you want to output JSON or transform to a string of comma separated values you should do that explicitly.